# Issues related to framing logic for RGB substring problem in c++

Tags: c++, string, substring

The other day I was solving a problem on **RGB Substring**. The question was:

You are given a string s consisting of n characters, each character is 'R', 'G' or 'B'.

You are also given an integer k. Your task is to change the minimum number of characters in the initial string s so that after the changes there will be a string of length k that is a substring of s, and is also a substring of the infinite string "RGBRGBRGB ..."

For example if the input string is BBBRR and k is 2, the output is 3

**How to approach this problem? I couldn't come up with an efficient algorithm to do the same**

Comment: Can you post the code you have so far?

Comment: Don't try to be efficient, first find something the works. It can help to break this down into steps : replacing a letter, comparing the strings, etc.
Then come back when you're stuck on a particular aspect.
No one writes 100% efficient algorithms on the first go ;) (At least I never do)

Comment: `For example if the input string is BBBRR, the output is 3` this makes no sense when compared with the problem definition. Output of what? Which `k` is given for this string?

Comment: @SergeyA sorry I missed the information about k. For this example k= 2. I will edit the question.

Comment: @ShadowMitia as I asked 'How to approach the problem?`, I really don't know the approach as I am very new in Competitive Programming world where I need to write codes with low execution time and space. Such constraints require more logical approach, I guess that's where I am failing. LOL!! Anyway I posted this question so that this community can help me with some ideas.

Comment: Still makes no sense. You are saying the task is ... *change the minimum number of characters*, yet the answer is integer. Also, if I read the task as *find the minimal number of characters which need to be changed*, the answer doesn't match - given the target length of 2, I only need to change 1 character - either second B to G, or last R to G. Could be other solutions which I do not immediately see.

Comment: Actually the output represents the number of minimal number of characters needed to change. Sorry again, I was also confused at first when I read the question

Comment: @SergeyA Okay I will post whatever I progressed so far.

Comment: @SergeyA yes you are right. It can't be 3 I just figured out. I think the answer should be 1 only. Actually this problem was given to me by my friend, I just contacted him and it turns out that he did a mistake.

Comment: Alright, here is the guide on how to approach a problem - first, make sure you understand the problem. Make sure sample problem and answer make sense to you. Than solve the sample problem manually. Come up with the answer and analyze your decision and thought process. Code that. Only after this step you should start optimizing your solution!

Comment: @SergeyA  I followed your proposal and prepared a solution.

Answer (score 0):

As SergeyA proposed. We first try to understand the problem and then solve it step by step. Then we write the code. OK.

So, the other day, I was solving the problem given to you.

1. First we have a string with random characters 'R', 'B', 'G'.
2. Then we have sequences of RGBRGBRGB...
3. We want to find a substring with a given length
4. We have to find a substring of the RGBRGBRGB... string
5. Then we need to compare this with the random string and check the minimum necessary character changes (or the maximum identical characters) at some position in the random string

From 4. we learn, that the result must be a substring of the RGBRGBRGB... string. So we are searching for a RGBRGBRGB... part. That is the key to the solution.

Since a substring can start anywhere in the RGBRGBRGB... we would have a lot of work, if we would not know the periodic repetition of the RGB. So, we need to find a substring of RGBRGBRGB... , GBRGBRGB... or  BRGBRGB... with the given substring length k.

So we plan to have 3 comparison runs with 1. RGBRGBRGB... , 2. GBRGBRGB... and 3.  BRGBRGB...

Next, we do a loop and compare k elements from the random charcacter source string and compare that with one of the periodic string. This we will do starting at position 1, then position 2 and so on.

When we have done at least k comparisons, we calculate the sum of equal characters. If this sum is bigger then the previous one, then we have found a new maximum and store this.

And so on and so on.

The comlexity is roughly 3*sizeof(input string)

I need only some additional memory for the counters (count: sizeof substring length).

Please see roughly 35 lines of code. I did not optimize so far.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
#include <numeric>


constexpr size_t SubStringSize = 6U;
const std::string testInput{ "RRRGBGBGGGBBRRRBGGBRGBGRRRGBBGRGGBBGRRBGRBBGGRGRGRGGRBRBGRRBGRGGBBGGBGBGBBBGGBBRBBRGRGGBRRR" };

const std::string rgbSourceCharacters("RGBRG");
inline char getRGB(size_t shift, size_t offset)
{
    return rgbSourceCharacters[shift + offset % 3U];
}

int main()
{
    // Some test string
    const size_t size = testInput.size();

    // Delta between Strings with RGBRGBRGB..... and testInput String
    std::vector<size_t> delta(SubStringSize);

    // This is the number of maxEquals for the given SubString Size
    size_t maxEquals{ 0U };

    // Position of char of best fitting substring
    size_t lastMaxEqualsPos{ 0U };
    // Which rgb sequence corresponds to ´best fitting substring
    size_t rgbShiftForMax{ 0U };

    // Check all possible RGB sequences, RGBRGBRGB... , GBRGBRGB..., BRGBRGB...
    for (size_t i = 0U; i < 3U; ++i)
    {
        // Set all values of our counters to 0
        std::fill(delta.begin(), delta.end(), 0U);

        // We will always begin with writing to the first position of the delta vector
        size_t indexInDeltaVector{ 0U };

        // Iterate over all characters of the source string
        for (size_t k = 0U; k < size; ++k)
        {
            // Check if the character is equal to RGB sequence, RGBRGBRGB... , GBRGBRGB..., BRGBRGB...
            delta[indexInDeltaVector] = (testInput[k] == getRGB(i,k)) ? 1U : 0U;
            // Increment index in delta vector, only until last position. Then stop
            if (indexInDeltaVector < (SubStringSize - 1U)) 
                ++indexInDeltaVector;
            // If we compared enough values
            else {
                // Calculate the sum of the previous n comparisons
                const size_t sum = std::accumulate(delta.begin(), delta.end(), 0U);
                // Check, if we found a new maximum
                if (sum > maxEquals) {
                    // If so then store relevant data
                    maxEquals = sum;
                    lastMaxEqualsPos = k - SubStringSize + 1U;
                    rgbShiftForMax = i;
                }
                // Make space for nect comparison
                std::rotate(delta.begin(), delta.begin() + 1U, delta.end());
            }
        }
    }
    // Show result
    std::cout << "\n\nFinal Result\n\nSource String:\n\n" << "0123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890\n" << testInput
        << "\n\nSubstring Length:  " << SubStringSize
        << "\nMax Equals:        " << maxEquals
        << "\nTo be changed:     " << SubStringSize - maxEquals
        << "\n\nSub String at pos: " << lastMaxEqualsPos
        << "\n\n--> " << testInput.substr(lastMaxEqualsPos, SubStringSize)
        << "\n--> "; 
    for (size_t offset = lastMaxEqualsPos; offset < lastMaxEqualsPos + SubStringSize; ++offset)
        std::cout << getRGB(rgbShiftForMax, offset);
    std::cout << '\n';

    return 0;
}
```

First optimization round. Reducing the functional lines of code to ~20:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
#include <numeric>

constexpr size_t SubStringSize = 6U;
constexpr std::string_view testInput{ "RRRGBGBGGGBBRRRBGGBRGBGRRRGBBGRGGBBGRRBGRBBGGRGRGRGGRBRBGRRBGRGGBBGGBGBGBBBGGBBRBBRGRGGBRRR" };

int main()
{
    // Delta between Strings with RGBRGBRGB..... and testInput String
    std::vector<size_t> delta(SubStringSize);

    // This is the result, the number of minDifferences for the given SubString Size
    size_t minDifference{ SubStringSize };

    // Check all possible RGB sequences, RGBRGBRGB... , GBRGBRGB..., BRGBRGB...
    for (size_t i = 0U; i < 3U; ++i)
    {
        // Set all values of our counters to 0
        std::fill(delta.begin(), delta.end(), 0U);

        // We will always begin with writing to the first position of the delta vector
        size_t indexInDeltaVector{ 0U };

        // Iterate over all characters of the source string
        for (size_t k = 0U; k < testInput.size(); ++k) {

            // Check, if the char is equal to RGB sequence, RGBRGBRGB... , GBRGBRGB..., BRGBRGB...
            delta[indexInDeltaVector] = (testInput[k] == "RGBRG"[k % 3U + i]) ? 0U : 1U;

            // Increment index in delta vector, only until last position. Then stop
            if (indexInDeltaVector < (SubStringSize - 1U))
                ++indexInDeltaVector;
            // If we compared enough values
            else {
                // Calculate the sum of the previous n comparisons
                const size_t sum = std::accumulate(delta.begin(), delta.end(), 0U);

                // Check, if we found a new minimum
                if (sum < minDifference) 
                    // If so then store relevant data
                    minDifference = sum;

                // Make space for next comparison
                std::rotate(delta.begin(), delta.begin() + 1U, delta.end());
            }
        }
    }
    // Show result
    std::cout << "\n\nFinal Result. Minimum characters to be changed: " << minDifference << '\n';

    return 0;
}
```